# Navigate slideshow with right/left arrow keys using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is kind of a slideshow that I made with jQuery. How can I use left and right keys on the keyboard to do the same thing as I am doing with the click event?

```
var x = 0;
$("#right-arrow").click(function(){
  if (x<3){
    x = x + 1;
    $("#wrapper").animate({ top: '-=400px' }, 1000);
  };
});
$("#left-arrow").click(function(){
  if (x>0){
    x = x - 1;
    $("#wrapper").animate({ top: '+=400px' }, 1000);
  };
});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Comment: Listen to the [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event) event and use [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) to figure out which key was used.

Answer (score 1):

*This* should work:

```
var x = 0;
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  //every time a key is pushed, this function will fire
  event.code === "ArrowLeft" && moveLeft();
  event.code === "ArrowRight" && moveRight();
});

$("#right-arrow").click(function() {
  moveRight();
});
$("#left-arrow").click(function() {
  moveLeft();
});

function moveLeft() {
  if (x > 0){
    x = x - 1;
    $("#wrapper").animate({ top: '+=400px' }, 1000);
  }
}
function moveRight() {
  if (x < 3){
    x = x + 1;
    $("#wrapper").animate({ top: '-=400px' }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work neither by clicking nor with the keys, & I don't know why. But I actually expected to have maybe just an additional code to my present one to provide these functions for the arrow keys too.

Comment: @Nocturne I don't know why it doesn't work, as I just seperated your code into two different functions. Is it at least working when clicking the arrows?

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard entries are normally bound with the following events: `keydown`, `keyup` and `keypress`. You can use any of them and check which key is pressed by checking it's `code` property. You should not use the `keyCode` property as it is deprecated.

**Edit**: From the comments it is understood that the `keypress` event is deprecated. So avoid using it anymore.

JavaScript key codes [here](https://keycode.info/)

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.code == 37)//left arrow
  {
   //your logic for left arrow press
  }
  if (e.code == 39)//rightarrow
  {
   //your logic for right arrow press
  }
});
```

Comment: You should not use the keypress event as it is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event#:~:text=The%20keypress%20event%20is%20fired,Shift%20%2C%20Ctrl%20%2C%20or%20Meta%20.